# error: ‘GlobalRNG’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, crypto++

I'm using Crypto++ to encrypt files in C++. And I'm using the code below.

It doesn't contain the headers files so I added my own :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/secblock.h>
#include <cryptopp/files.h>
#include <cryptopp/queue.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
#include <cryptopp/base64.h>
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
#include <cryptopp/integer.h>
#include <cryptopp/dh.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/modes.h>
#include <cryptopp/eax.h>
#include <cryptopp/tea.h>
#include <cryptopp/blowfish.h>
#include <cryptopp/pssr.h>
#include <cryptopp/rsa.h>
#include <cryptopp/nbtheory.h>
#include <cryptopp/eccrypto.h>
#include <cryptopp/oids.h>
#include <cryptopp/modes.h>
#include <cryptopp/gzip.h>
#include <cryptopp/blowfish.h>
#include <cryptopp/rsa.h>
#include <cryptopp/rng.h>
#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
#include <cryptopp/rdrand.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;
```

But unfortunately the code doesn't work 
Saying that the GlobalRNG is not declared !

```
error: ‘GlobalRNG’ was not declared in this scope
```

I googled and kept looking for a solution for 2 days i found that it's a bug and fixed but i'm having the latest version : 5.6.3 !

So i really don't know why this error is showing !

Comment: grep the header files to find the header file that declares this, then `#include` it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik of course i did that !!!! and i didn't find any that declares it !!!

Comment: I am deeply suspicious of that link.  There is no way that properly written asymmetric cryptography will produce "data inconsistency errors".  There is also no need to make the symmetric key consist of letters - just produce enough random bytes, and use that.  (To be clear: the approach of encrypting the bulk data with a symmetric key is correct.)

Comment: @MartinBonner any links or keywords that might help me do a research ?

Comment: The crypto++ documentation would be a good place to start.  If you have difficulty with the crypto, you could ask on crypto.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com (depending on the slant of your question).

Comment: Take a look at file `validate.h` line 96

Comment: @BiagioFesta Worked as charm ! good you please answer the question ? 
Another thing if anyone want help me ! when i run it i'm getting this error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::BERDecodeErr'`

Comment: You are including more headers than you show. The headers your are showing are for the Crypto++ ***library***. The error you are receiving comes from a header in the Crypto++ ***test suite***. Or, you are including source files from the ***test suite*** (and not just the ***library***). Also see [RandomNumberGenerator | Test Suite and GlobalRNG](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator#Test_Suite_and_GlobalRNG) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version *5.6.3* `GlobalRNG` is defined in the file `validate.h`, as:

```
// Functions that need a RNG; uses AES inf CFB mode with Seed.
CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator & GlobalRNG();
```

Just add this inclusion:

```
#include <cryptopp/validate.h>
```

to solve definition problem.

Comment: `GlobalRNG()` is for the Crypto++ test and validation suite. He should probably use his own generator rather than including the one from the test suite. Also see [RandomNumberGenerator | Test Suite and GlobalRNG](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator#Test_Suite_and_GlobalRNG) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: @jww Sure, I just answered his question. I cannot check the soundness of the tutorial he's following. Anyway I'm going to add that information to the answer for completeness

Answer (score 0):

`GloablaRNG` is part of testing and bench-marking. It should not be part of the library proper (i.e., `libcryptopp.a` or `libcryptopp.so`). If your programs are complaining about a missing `GloablaRNG`, then the library was cross-contaminated with some of the testing and bench-marking gear.

These are the files used for testing and bench-marking. They should ***not*** be included in your build of the library or your project:

- validate.h
- bench.h
- test.cpp
- bench1.cpp, bench2.cpp
- validat0.cpp, validat1.cpp, validat2.cpp, validat3.cpp
- datatest.cpp, regtest.cpp, fipsalgt.cpp, dlltest.cpp

---

You are free to use a function called `GlobalRNG()`. Here's how its used in the library's test and bench-marking gear. But you might consider using an `AutoSeededRandomPool` instead. The `AutoSeededRandomPool` is a PGP-style generator, and its seeded from `/dev/urandom`, `/dev/srandom`, `/dev/random` or the Windows entropy pool.

***Declaration in validate.h***

```
NAMESPACE_BEGIN(CryptoPP)
NAMESPACE_BEGIN(Test)

CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator & GlobalRNG();

NAMESPACE_END  // Test
NAMESPACE_END  // CryptoPP
```

***Definition in test.cpp***

```
NAMESPACE_BEGIN(CryptoPP)
NAMESPACE_BEGIN(Test)

ANONYMOUS_NAMESPACE_BEGIN
OFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption s_globalRNG;
NAMESPACE_END

RandomNumberGenerator & GlobalRNG()
{
    return dynamic_cast<RandomNumberGenerator&>(s_globalRNG);
}
NAMESPACE_END  // Test
NAMESPACE_END  // CryptoPP
```

***Seeding in test.cpp***

```
// Don't do this in production because it creates a deterministic generator
OFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption& aesg = dynamic_cast<OFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption&>(Test::GlobalRNG());
aesg.SetKeyWithIV((byte *)seed.data(), 16, (byte *)seed.data());
```

---

A lot of folks have had this problem over the years. At Crypto++ 6.0, we moved `GlobalRNG()` into the `Test` namespace. `Test` is a new namespace, and we hope `Test::GlobalRNG()` will provide the signals that something is amiss in your library build or project configuration.

Also see [Issue 379, Add Test namespace within CryptoPP namespace](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/379) and  [Commit 73836e58a5f5c11c](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/73836e58a5f5c11cd7bf7db76e9d02013975fc9a).